# Vim: How to map yank till to multiple characters

Tags: vim

I want to do something like map

`df` to these all these commands

```
yt) //yank till the ")" character
yt}
yt]
```

Example:

```
111)
222}
333]
```

Starting from the beginning of any of these lines, running `df` should copy any of the lines into the clip board register.
I want to do this since its less work than having to look what the closing character is :)

I tried to do something like this but it doesn't seem to work....

`map df ys) <bar> ys} <bar> ys] <CR>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$y0
```

would do what you ask in the given sample in an agnostic way:

- `$` moves the cursor to the last character of the line, whatever it is,
- `y0` yanks the text from the current character (*exclusive*) to the first character (*inclusive*).

If what you want is more generic than your example, something like "goes from here to the next closing bracket", then creating a custom motion seems more canonical than messing with the operator `d` and the motion `f`.

It should look like this:

```
xnoremap gb <Cmd>call search('.\ze[)}\]]')<CR>
onoremap gb <Cmd>normal vgb<CR>
```

which can be used with *any* operator, not just `y`:

```
dgb
ygb
etc.
```

The snippet above is the blueprint for custom motions:

- you create a visual mode mapping that covers what you want to cover,
- you use it in an operator-pending mode mapping.

Now, the hard part is finding available keys.

See `:help omap-info`, `:help :map-cmd`, `:help :call`, `:help search()`.

Comment: Oh nice, thanks. On my computer the above works only for `vgb` but for things like `dgb` its behavior is to delete only one character ?

Comment: Sorry, I added a useless `!`. The revised snippet should work, now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mapping:

```
noremap df y/[)}\]]<cr>
```

Instead of using the motion `t`, it uses a regular expression motion `/` which will match any character inside the square brackets (the closing square bracket itself has to be escaped).

Note: you may choose a different mapping key, because by remapping `df` you will loose an important native feature (delete until a given character is found).

Comment: Note that this will highlight all `)}]`s in the screen if `hlsearch` is enabled, [which might not be to everyone's liking](https://i.imgur.com/Y2OW758.png). To avoid that, one can use `:help search()` directly in the mapping or `/` in a function called in the mapping.